# convert float to string preserving decimals

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

My float is 100.0 when i convert it to string it becomes 100.

```
rmt.MinNumber = 0.0;
rmt.MaxNumber = 100.0;

rmt.MaxLength = rmt.MinNumber.ToString() + " - " + rmt.MaxNumber.ToString();
```

I know I can do

```
rmt.MinNumber.ToString("0.0");
```

but that is also a setting saved in rmt.Decimal so

if rmt.Decimal = 1
then **rmt.MaxLength = 100.0**

if rmt.Decimal = 2
then **rmt.MaxLength = 100.00** and so on...

How can i convert it to string preserving its decimal value

### UPDATE

As suggested by CodeFuller

```
public static class Helper
{
   public static string Format(this float f, int n)
    {
        return f.ToString($"0.{new String('0', n)}");
    }
}
```

but currently it is giving me error ) expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could still use `ToString("0.0")` method but you should build format specifier at run time since number of digits after the dot will vary.

Consider using following extension method:

```
public static class FloatExtensions
{
    public static string Format(this float f, int n)
    {
        // return f.ToString($"0.{new String('0', n)}");
        return f.ToString("0." + new String('0', n));
    }
}

rmt.MaxLength = rmt.MinNumber.Format(rmt.Decimal)
```

Comment: $"0.{new String('0', n)}" compiler also says unexpected character '$'

Comment: hey did u mean @ instead of $?

Comment: It's a string interpolation available since C# 6.0. Probably you're using some of previous versions. Check my answer update, it should work for you.

Comment: Cool! that was awesome!!